# C using fscanf and printf returns weird values?

Tags: c, file, printf

I'm learning C at school, and I am having problems learning how to read from files.

This question is not homework, it's a practice exercise in a book I'm working through.

My file is a .txt file named Letters.txt.

It contains all of the data inside these 's: '#Alphabet.123.45ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.

There is the '>' symbol, then the word Alphabet, then a (.) then 123, then a (.) then 45, then 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.

The first problem I'm having is that when I try to read the file and print it to the screen to see if I'm even reading it correctly, my console just prints out MZÉ. I have no idea what that is.

My code to do this is:

```
   FILE *fp;
   char *fname;

   fname = "Letters.txt";

   fp = fopen(fname, "r");

   char *buff[100];

   fscanf(fp, "%s", buff);
   printf("%s", buff); 

   fclose(fp);
```

Secondly, the actual exercise is supposed to be to split this input into separate variables:

Discarding the initial character, a string with Alphabet.123.45, and a string with 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.

I keep finding REGEX tutorials online, but I'm not really familiar with those. For reference I am only versed in Java, Javascript, PHP, MySQL,and JQuery, previously.

Comment: try using fprintf()...hope your problem will be solved...

Comment: It's `char buff[100]` instead of `char *buff[100]`

Comment: Does the file start with a `#` or a `>`? You've said both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    char *fname = "Letters.txt";

    fp = fopen(fname, "r");

    char buff[100];
    fscanf(fp, "%99s", buff);
    printf("%s\n", buff); 

    fclose(fp);

    char field[4][32];
    sscanf(buff, "%*c%31[A-Za-z].%31[0-9].%31[0-9]%31s", field[0], field[1], field[2],field[3]);
    printf("%s\n", field[0]);
    printf("%s\n", field[1]);
    printf("%s\n", field[2]);
    printf("%s\n", field[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like this compilation of the parts, but thanks to everyone. I think I am understanding a bit more about how to use these functions, but my printf("%s\n", buff); still outputs MZÉ. I don't understand where it's getting that data from.

Comment: @ShawnKarber File does not exist(you might have failed to open the file.) or the encoding of the file will be assumed to be a multi-byte character.

Answer (score 1):

I see several problems here.

- You should zero out buff. Random bytes in memory not being equal to 0 could cause overwriting of data on printf. Plus c strings are terminated by zero (null).
- Second, you should check the value returned by `fscanf`. If it is a negative number, you have an error. If it is a positive number, it indicates the number of characters read in. If that number is greater than 100, you will have overwritten your buffer (bad).
- Third, as was pointed out by Cool Guy, you should remove the `*` before `buff` as you want a single string array, not a pointer to an array of strings.

---

In general, when dealing with library functions in c, you should check all return values for negative numbers. If You get a negative number, you should call `get_errno()` to see what went wrong. For example, on opening a file, it is possible to fail to open for different reasons, and your program might want to do something different depending on which reason the `open()` call failed.

Comment: Okay I've made the changes everyone has suggested, and I added      "printf("%d", sc);" with sc being = to fscanf(fp, "%s", buff) and it returns 1. Why is it only getting 1 character?

Comment: @ShawnKarber And, does it work? Could you update the code in the original question (or append the modified code after your question as an edit?) If our answers helped, you should upvote the answers that helped and accept one of them.

Comment: @ShawnKarber , Read what `fscanf` returns

Answer (score 0):

Remove the asterisk before `buff` and then,it should work fine! Also you must check `if(fp!=NULL)` to see if file opened

Answer (score 0):

you need to check the return value from fopen to insure it has successfully opened the file. If it fails you'll get garbage back from fscanf. fscanf also returns a useful value you should check too